# Is this the right way to make dataframe using nested for loops ? The range function is no properly givin data for the dataframe ..Whats wrong here?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

```py
for carbon_flow in range(0,1000,100):  
         for non_carbon_flow in range(0,1000,100):  
           CFS = carbon_flow_share()
```

I am not able to combine all of these into a dataframe , how do i go about it ?

This is what i did ,i want to make a single table with these data :

```
data = []  
for carbon_flow in range(0,1000,100):  
 for non_carbon_flow in range(100,1000,100):  
    CFS = carbon_share()  
        data = [{'carbon_flow': carbon_flow, 'non_carbon_flow':   non_carbon_flow,'carbon Share':RES}]  
         
pd.DataFrame(data) 

print(data)
```

but this is the output i am getting :

```
[{'carbon_flow': 900, 'non_carbon_flow': 900, 'carbon Share': 0.5}]
```

I want these in a single column with the values from the for loop, what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

First, append the new record in the interior of the loop, rather than overwriting the whole list:

```
data.append({'carbon_flow': carbon_flow, 'non_carbon_flow':   non_carbon_flow,'carbon Share':CFS})
```

Your next error's in the last two lines.  Replace them with

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
print(df)
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html for more details and options